# Add lines to a summary notification Android

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

I'm new to Android Development so I don't really know how do/search some things, if there is a place where my question already got answered please tell me, or if I'm trying to do something that I shouldn't, thanks.

So my problem is that I want to create different notifications with my app and I read/want to create a single summary notification each time I get more than 1 message, I didn't had much problem creating this but I don't have any idea on how to update it each time I get a new notification.

Also I've read from Android developers(http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html) that if i create a group and add notifications to it they should be in a stack. What does it means? I tried and it seems to be the same with or without the group, notifications are shown as single.. The only difference I've seen is that when i call the summary notification with the same group name as the others they dissapear, is that the meaning of stacking?

Sorry for my bad english maybe I misunderstood something, hope you can help me.

Here is the code I writed:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
}

final static String GROUP_KEY_EMAILS = "group_key_emails";
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;
int n =0;
String sender1="Marco";
String sender2="Michele";
String text1="ci sei?";
String text2="Okk";
public  void btn1(View v)
{

    Notification notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(sender1)
            .setContentText(text1)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_EMAILS)
            .build();


    notificationManager.notify(0, notif);
    n++;


    }

    public void btn2(View v)
    {

    Notification notif2 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(sender2)
            .setContentText(text2)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_EMAILS)
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(1, notif2);
    n++;
  }

  public void btn3(View v)
  {
    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher);


    Notification summaryNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("MyApp")
            .setSubText(Integer.toString(n)+" nuovi messaggi")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
                    .addLine(sender1+"  "+text1)
                    .addLine(sender2+"  "+text2)
                    .setBigContentTitle(Integer.toString(n)+" nuovi messaggi")
                    .setSummaryText("nonsocosascrivere.com"))
            .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_EMAILS)
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(3, summaryNotification);



  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notifications can be updated by providing the same notification "ID", for example in your code, your notification id is "3":

```
notificationManager.notify(3, summaryNotification);
```

from the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int, android.app.Notification)

Right now, you are correctly using `setGroup` but because you give the same notification id, it is replacing the content instead of "stacking" the notifications.

Give "new" notifications separate id's. Give a notification that needs to be updated the same id. (An example of an "updated notification" might be a reminder that you want to have post "15 minutes until your appointment" - if the user does not dismiss it, you might update it later to say "10 minutes..." but you would not want this to "stack" - the user does not need to see all of the notifications, only the most recent.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but where am I giving the same ID? Also maybe I didn't write well, sorry, What I want is to update the summary notification each time I get a new message, but how do I do it if I don't know what's in the summary in that moment so I can update it adding an extra line next to the others?  I want to change it dynamically as Whatsapp/Gmail etc.